# Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I have converted an app from angular 8 to angular14
I have a form array that is suddenly giving this error

cfs-detail.component.html:13 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')
at getControlValidators (forms.mjs:901:20)
at setUpValidators (forms.mjs:3065:24)
at setUpFormContainer (forms.mjs:3182:5)
at FormGroupDirective._setUpFormContainer (forms.mjs:4996:9)
at FormGroupDirective.addFormGroup (forms.mjs:4883:14)
at FormGroupName.ngOnInit (forms.mjs:3732:28)
at callHook (core.mjs:2498:22)
at callHooks (core.mjs:2467:17)
at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.mjs:2418:9)
at selectIndexInternal (core.mjs:9826:17)

The array does not render correctly.
Here is a picture of how it initially loads.
Tabbing through the controls seems to make it behave better
until you eventually get to something that looks correct.

[image: picture of form array with problem]

This is what I am expecting. It is a CSS grid. The CSS was correct before the angular upgrade. I am pretty sure this is something I did trying to make all the 'initial value
errors go away.

[image: Here is the form array as it should appear]

Here it the HTML template

```
<ng-template #loading>
    <div   >loading...</div>
    <div *ngIf="!year">please pass in year</div>
    <div *ngIf="!showBy">please pass in periodChoice!</div>
    <div *ngIf="!myPeriods">periods have not loaded</div>

</ng-template>  
 
 
<span *ngIf="showBy ; else loading">
    <span *ngIf="year ; else loading">
        <div class="year">
            <button (click)="toggleForm()" id="btnToggle">{{toggleFormText}}</button>
            
            {{year}}   
            
        </div>
       
        <div *ngIf="myPeriods   as periods  ; else loading "    class="cfs-12month-grid {{showBy}} y{{year}}">
            <ng-container [formGroup]="myFormGroup">
                 
                <ng-container  formArrayName="periods" >
                   

                    <ng-container *ngFor="let perFrm   of periods12.controls ;let i = index;" formGroupName="i"   >
                         
                        
                        <p  class="fieldlabel cfs {{showBy}} {{monthShortName(myPeriods[i])}}">{{shortDate(myPeriods[i]) }} 
                        </p>
                            
                            
                        <input  
                        class="fieldvalue cfs {{showBy}} {{ monthShortName(myPeriods[i]) }}"  
                        type="text" value="{{roundedAmount(myPeriods[i])}}" 
                        formControlName="Amount"
                     />  
                        
                        
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>    

        </div>
    </span>
</span>
```

Here is the component code

```
import { Component, OnInit , AfterViewInit
  , Input, Output, SimpleChanges 
  , ElementRef, EventEmitter, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
 import { AbstractControl  , FormBuilder, FormGroup   
    , Validators
    , RequiredValidator, MaxLengthValidator, MinLengthValidator, FormControl, FormArray
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable   } from 'rxjs';
import { Tools } from '../../tools';
import { CashFlowStringPeriod } from '../cash-flow-string-period';
import { cashFlowStringService } from '../services/cash-flow-string.service';
import { cashFlowStringPeriodService } from '../services/cash-flow-string-period.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cfs-12months',
  templateUrl: './cfs12-months.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cfs12-months.component.css']
})
export class cfs12MonthsComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() showBy : string="byQtr";
@Input() cfsPeriods : CashFlowStringPeriod[];
@Input() year : number;

    myFormGroup : FormGroup;  //do not 'strong type' this
                                  //2020 10 25 gregm its making me strong type it...
 
 

 toggleFormText:string="-";
 toggleFormVisible:number=1; 

 
  public myPeriods : CashFlowStringPeriod[]=[];
    formatter_shortMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', { month: 'short' });

  constructor(private myFormBuilder: FormBuilder
          , private cfsService : cashFlowStringService
          , private cfspService : cashFlowStringPeriodService ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
 


  buildForm(){
    this.myFormGroup = this.myFormBuilder.group(
      {
        //simply add a formArray to the group
          periods : this.myFormBuilder.array([])
      }
          ,{ updateOn: "blur" }
      );
      
      this.myFormGroup.valueChanges.subscribe((data: any)   => {
        this.saveMainForm();
      });
      
      
    }  //end buildForm
    

    get periods12()   {
       
       return this.myFormGroup.get("periods") as FormArray;

    }

    populateForm(){
       console.log('cf12pf pCount',this.myPeriods.length);
      this.myPeriods.forEach( cfsp =>{
             const periodForm = this.myFormBuilder.group({
                id : [cfsp.id, Validators.required]
                , cashFlowId : [cfsp.cashFlowId, Validators.required]
                , FlowDate : [cfsp.FlowDate, Validators.required]
                , Amount : [cfsp.Amount, Validators.required]
            });
             this.periods12.push(periodForm); 
               
          } //callback
        );// forEach
           console.log('leave pf', this.periods12); 
      }

    
  filterMyPeriods(){
    this.myPeriods = this.cfsPeriods.filter( cfsp => 
           {
              
            let d:Date = this.getDateFromStringOrObject(cfsp.FlowDate);
            return (this.year  == d.getFullYear()) ;
          }
      );
      let f=1;
  }

  getDateFromStringOrObject(input_ : any) : Date{
      let s: string="";
      if (typeof input_ === 'object'){
          s= input_.formatted;
      }else{
        s=input_;
      }
      let d:Date = new Date(s);
      return d;
  } 

 

   public monthShortName (cfsp_ : CashFlowStringPeriod) : string {
    let d= this.getDateFromStringOrObject(cfsp_.FlowDate) ;
     let s:string =this.formatter_shortMonth.format(d).toLowerCase(); 
     console.log("month SN",s);

    return s;
}

   public roundedAmount( cfsp_  : CashFlowStringPeriod) : number{
     return Tools.roundToNplaces(cfsp_.Amount,2);
   }

   formatter_shortDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat( );
 

    shortDate( cfsp_ : CashFlowStringPeriod) : string {
      let d= this.getDateFromStringOrObject(cfsp_.FlowDate) ;
        let s:string =  this.formatter_shortDate.format(d);
        console.log("shortdate",s);
        return s;
   }
}
```

Comment: Surely something will break when you upgrade skipping 5 major versions. Maybe try upgrading 8 => 9 => 10 etc? When something finally breaks, you should see what and read changelog of Angular to see what you need change in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps someone in the future. There are no results when searching the title of the question...

My mistake was a simple and aggravating one.

formGroupName does not = 'i', it should equal the value of i.

so

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let perFrm   of periods12.controls ;let i = index;" formGroupName="i"   >
```

should be  ( square brackets around formGroupName )

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let perFrm   of periods12.controls ;let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i"   >
```

I can not remember which error messages led me to tinkering w/ the *ngFor statements. I believe it was related to variables now requiring initialization.